# How to remove dots from a filename without removing them from the extension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I am iterating through a folder that has files of different extensions. I want to remove dots (`'.'`) from the filename, **but not the extension**. If I simply do this:

```
def filename_replacer(file_name):
    extension = file_name[-4:]
    raw_name = file_name[:-4]       
    new_name = raw_name.replace(".", "_")
    new_name = new_name + extension
    return new_name

file = "Remove.TheDotReport.xlsx"
cleaned_file = filename_replacer(file)
```

It comes out incorrect (ex: `Remove_TheDotReport_xlxs`). How can I consistently remove the dots in the file without messing up the extension?

Comment: simplest answer...  increase your slice for the extension to `[-5:]`, which will cover extensions of 4 characters + the dot.  Might fail in very odd corner case where you have a 3 letter extension and the filename ends in a dot, if that is even legal.  I'm sure a regex pro will have some other options...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `os.path.splitext` to get the extension out first.

```
import os

def filename_replacer(filename):
  fname, fext = os.path.splitext(filename)
  return fname.replace(".", "_") + fext
```

Comment: I like this, it is very clear

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.4, a convenient way for working with paths is the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) built-in library. It treats paths as *objects* instead of simple *strings*.

Since Python 3.9, a new method was added - [`with_stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_stem) - which only changes the name of the file without the extension. So this can be done quite easily:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("Remove.TheDotReport.xlsx")
print(path.with_stem(path.stem.replace('.', '_')))
# Remove_TheDotReport.xlsx
```

For older versions, you can still use the [`with_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_name) method with a bit more work (adding the extension separately):

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("Remove.TheDotReport.xlsx")
print(path.with_name(path.stem.replace('.', '_') + path.suffix))
# Remove_TheDotReport.xlsx
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for a bash script to remove dots from the filename and keep the extension dot if you want to change for anyone file (`'dir /b *.filename'`) give filename here.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *') do call :dot "%%a"
pause
goto :EOF
:dot
set "var=%~n1"
set "var=%var:.= %"
ren %1 "%var%%~x1"
```